# IdentityServer4 500 internal error, misssing EpochTimeExtensions when using authorize endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net, identityserver4

I am creating a wep api backend for xamarin forms application with ASP.NET,
i'm using identityserver4 for authentication and authorization.
I want to use the authorization code workflow but i'm encountering a problem when i try to start the authorization/authentication request.

The error i receive is : 
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'IdentityModel.EpochTimeExtensions' from assembly 'IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=e7877f4675df049f'.

I haven't found a solution to this problem anywhere on the internet.

This is my Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }


    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //services.AddAutoMapper();
        services.AddDbContext<SqlDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.GetResources())
            .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.GetApis())
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();
        services.AddControllers()
            .AddNewtonsoftJson();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseIdentityServer();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World !");
            });
        });
    }
}
```

This is my config.cs:

```
public class Config
{
    public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApis()
    {
        return new List<ApiResource>
        {
            new ApiResource("Test", "TestService")
        };
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetResources()
    {
        return new List<IdentityResource>
        {
            new IdentityResources.OpenId()
        };
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
    {
        return new List<Client>
        {
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "client",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                RequireClientSecret = false,
                RequireConsent = false,
                AllowedScopes = new List<string>{ "Test" , "openid"},
                AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                RedirectUris = new List<String> {
                    "https://localhost:44392/account/test/"
                }
            }
        };
    }
 }
```

And this is my request url :

https://localhost:44392/connect/authorize?client_id=client&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://localhost:44392/account/test/&scope=Test openid&nonce=5&state=5

I hope someone here can help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of identity server4 are you using

Comment: The latest one, but i have tried also with older versions and it didn't work

Comment: Check your identityModel version it should be >=3.10.6 and identityServer version 2.1.2 or greater

Comment: The IdentityModel that comes inside the IdentityServer4 is of version 4.0.0 Preview.
But i tried also installing identitymodel explicitly in different versions, and it still didn't work

Comment: try to unistall identityserver4  and install with 2.1.2 , issue may be due to  4.0.0 Preview ,the preview version or uncheck the include pre release

Comment: It solved the error, but i don't know where i can retrieve the authorization code so that i can exchange it for an access token

Comment: can you open a new question for auth code